# Get only InnerText of this node excluding children

Tags: c#, html, string, html-agility-pack

Since i'm still not that familiar with XPath i'm prefering LINQ with `HtmlAgilityPack`. I think this is one of the cases where i need an XPath solution. So i need your help.

Consider this simplified HTML snippet:

```
<td><b>Billing informations:</b>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: #757575; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
                Invoice-Number:1534753<br />Transactioncode: 1WF772582A4041717
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

This is part of a larger HTML page but it demonstrates the issue i have. I need to extract the `Invoice-Number` and `TransactionCode`. Sometimes the text is in a span and sometimes directly in the cell like here. So i need a way that works in both cases.

I've tried this:

```
var invoiceCell = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
    .FirstOrDefault(cell => cell.InnerText.Contains("Invoice-Number"));
if (invoiceCell != null)
{
    string text = invoiceCell.InnerText;
    // use string methods to extract both values
}
```

The problem is that `invoiceCell.InnerText` returns the outermost cell's `InnerText`, not the cell that contains the `Invoice-Number`. So `text` contains also "Billing informations":

```
Billing informations:



                Invoice-Number:1534753Transactioncode: 1WF772582A4041818
```

While i could use string methods or regex to extract both values in this case this is very error-prone since the larger html page contains many nested tables. I just want the `InnerText` of the inner-most cell. Maybe there's also a LINQ solution to solve this issue, then i'd prefer that.

**Update** i've noticed that using `LastOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault` might be a viable workaround because that seems to return the innermost cell that matches the condition:

```
var invoiceCell = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
    .LastOrDefault(cell => cell.InnerText.Contains("Invoice-Number"));
```

Comment: Would it be OK for you using `.StartsWith`instead of `.Contains`?

Comment: @LocEngineer: maybe with `InnerText.TrimStart().StartsWith` because without `Trim` it doesn't work. But even then, i have no control over the document. No idea if it will work in future so i wanted to use `Contains` for the cell-filter. However, interesting idea.

Comment: Yes, if it's always in a td, LastOrDefault would probably be the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another alternative using XPath to cover both cases --when the target text is directly inside the cell and when the same is wrapped in a span :

```
var xpath = "//td[contains(text(),'Invoice-Number') or contains(span,'Invoice-Number')]";
var invoiceCell = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
```

Comment: The combination of `text()` and the filter by `Invoive-Number` was what i didnt know. Learned something new, thanks. I should really work on my xpath skills.